# Implementing circuit breaker when there is no service call

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I have a spring boot application which works like a data service.Its main job is to

1. consume messages from other applications via JMS
2. do filteration and validation
3. publish to another application via JMS

I want to implement a circuit breaker like implementation, where if application is receving exception while publishing, consuming messages need to stop and as exception ends consuming needs to resume.

I am trying to find solutions via circuitbreaker via resillence 4j, I know that circuitbreaker only works HTTP responses I want to implement like circuitbreaker when my service call failes to publish the messages.

I was also working on stopping consumer to stop message processing via JmsListernerEndpointRegistry and get listeners and call stop method, but it is also not working.

Mainly I want to implement like below

```
public void myServiceMethod() {
        try {
            // when service call that may throw an exception
            throw new JMSPublishException("Something went wrong!");
        } catch JMSPublishException e) {
            // Handle the exception and track it with the Circuit Breaker
            CircuitBreaker.decorateCheckedRunnable(circuitBreaker, () -> {
                // Handle the exception or perform any necessary fallback logic
                System.out.println("Fallback logic executed");
            }).run();
        }
    }
```